# Unable to Parse the Manually upload Json File

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

My objective is to create the page which would either take the inline json-data in the html-page itself; or provide the upload button to let user choose the json file of their choice. I have moved from YUI3 TO Jquery and things are little bit challenging for me.  I tried but this is no refreshing when I upload "details.txt" file.

**"Updated Comments:"**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">   
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js' dataTables></script>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fiddle.jshell.net/css/normalize.css">
  
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fiddle.jshell.net/css/result-light.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.dataTables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
      <script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdn.dataTables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>    
   
</head>
<body> 
  <script id="data" type="application/json">
    {
     "sEcho": 1,
 "iTotalRecords": "11",
 "iTotalDisplayRecords": "11",
 "aaData": [
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Other browsers",
      "2": "All others",
      "3": "-",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "U",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Trident",
      "2": "AOL browser (AOL desktop)",
      "3": "Win XP",
      "4": "6",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Camino 1.0",
      "3": "OSX.2+",
      "4": "1.8",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Camino 1.5",
      "3": "OSX.3+",
      "4": "1.8",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Misc",
      "2": "Dillo 0.8",
      "3": "Embedded devices",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "X",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Epiphany 2.20",
      "3": "Gnome",
      "4": "1.8",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Firefox 1.0",
      "3": "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
      "4": "1.7",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Firefox 1.5",
      "3": "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
      "4": "1.8",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Firefox 2.0",
      "3": "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
      "4": "1.8",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Firefox 3.0",
      "3": "Win 2k+ / OSX.3+",
      "4": "1.9",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Misc",
      "2": "IE Mobile",
      "3": "Windows Mobile 6",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "C",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    }
 ]
}
 </script> 

<script id="output" type="application/json"></script>

<div class="custom-file">

    <span class="button">Choose a file</span>
    <input type="file" id="file" />
</div>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th width="4%"></th>
   <th width="25%">Rendering engine</th>
   <th width="20%">Browser</th>
   <th width="25%">Platform(s)</th>
   <th width="16%">Engine version</th>
   <th width="10%">CSS grade</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="5" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tfoot>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th>Rendering engine</th>
   <th>Browser</th>
   <th>Platform(s)</th>
   <th>Engine version</th>
   <th>CSS grade</th>
  </tr>
 </tfoot>
</table>
  
<div id="meta"></div><br>


<input id="file-select" type="file" name="files[]"  />
<hr>
<button id="read">Read</button>
<hr>

<!--button id="search-beginning">Find first</button>
<input type="text" id="find-first-pattern" placeholder="Regexp pattern" />
<button id="search-next">Find next</button>
-->
<hr>

<button id="searchAll">Find all</button>
<input type="text" id="find-all-pattern" placeholder="Regexp pattern" />

<hr>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
var ajax="";
var fileselected="";
var olderfile="";
var data="";
var oTable="";
    var firstDivContent="";
    var secondDivContent="" ;
 
 
 
$(document).ready(function() {

 alert("ready");
 data=JSON.parse($("#data").text());
 oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
 destroy: true,
 data : data.aaData
}); 


function fnFormatDetails ( nTr ) {
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
    var sOut = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Rendering engine:</td><td>'+aData[2]+' '+aData[5]+'</td></tr>';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Link to source:</td><td>Could provide a link here</td></tr>';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Extra info:</td><td>And any further details here (images etc)</td></tr>';
    sOut += '</table>';
     
    return sOut;
}

//live is deprcated
$('#example tbody td img').on( 'click', function () {
        var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
        if ( oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr) )
        {
            /* This row is already open - close it */
            this.src = "../examples_support/details_open.png";
            //this.src = "http://l.yimg.com/rz/d/yahoo_news_en-US_s_f_p_168x21_news.png";
            oTable.fnClose( nTr );
        }
        else
        {
            /* Open this row */
            this.src = "../examples_support/details_close.png";
            oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(nTr), 'details' );
        }
    });  

    $('#file').change(function(){
  //data=JSON.parse($("#output").html()) ;
  olderfile=fileselected;
  alert("We: "+olderfile);
  fileselected =$(this).siblings('.text').text(this.value);
        $(this).siblings('.text').text(this.value || 'Nothing selected');
  fileselected = $('input[type=file]').val().replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, '');
  if (olderfile!=fileselected && fileselected!="" ) { 
   alert("We: "+fileselected);
   } else {
   alert("No Changes Made ");
   }
    });  

  
  oTable.fnDraw();  

}); 
 
$("#searchAll").click(function() {
//Destroy the added Data
oTable.dataTable().fnClearTable();
oTable.dataTable().fnDestroy();
alert("Destroyed");
        data=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($("#output").text()));
  oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
 destroy: false, 
 data : data.aaData  
  }); 
alert("Reinitialize Data");
oTable.fnDraw();
alert("Draw Data.aadata");  
//oTable.api().ajax.reload();   
//alert("Reload Data");  
    }); 
 
$(function() {
function LineNavigator(readChunk, decode, options) {
    var self = this;
    
    // verification
    if (typeof (readChunk) != 'function') throw 'readChunk argument must be function(offset, length, callback)'
    if (typeof (decode) != 'function') throw 'decode argument must be function(buffer, callback)'    

    // private    
    options = options ? options : {};
    var milestones =    options.milestones    ? options.milestones    : [];    // { firstLine, lastLine, offset, length }
    var chunkSize =     options.chunkSize     ? options.chunkSize     : 1024 * 4;
    var newLineCode =   '\n'.charCodeAt(0);
    var splitPattern =  /\r?\n/;
    
    // Searches for milestone
    var getPlaceToStart = function (index) {
        for (var i = milestones.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (milestones[i].lastLine < index) 
                return { firstLine: milestones[i].lastLine + 1, offset: milestones[i].offset + milestones[i].length };
        }
        return { firstLine: 0, offset: 0 };
    }
    
    // Count lines in chunk and offset of last line, saves milestones
    var examineChunk = function(buffer, offset, bytesRead, firstLine) {
        var saveMilestone = milestones.length == 0 || milestones[milestones.length - 1].offset < offset;
        var lastLine = firstLine - 1;
        var length = 0;

        // Search for delimiters
        for (var i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++) {
            if (buffer[i] == newLineCode) {
                lastLine++;
                length = i + 1;
            }
        }

        // Describe milestone
        var milestone = {
            firstLine: firstLine,
            lastLine: lastLine,
            offset: offset,
            length: length
        };

        if (saveMilestone)
            milestones.push(milestone);

        // Describe beginning of next milestone
        var milestoneClone = Object.create(milestone);
        milestoneClone.place = { firstLine: lastLine + 1, offset: offset + length };

        return milestoneClone;
    };
    
    // Get lines 
    var getLines = function(buffer, length, callback) {
        decode(buffer.slice(0, length), function(text) {
            var lines = text.split(splitPattern);
            if (lines.length > 0 && lines[lines.length - 1] == "")
                lines = lines.slice(0, lines.length - 1);
            callback(lines);
        });
    };
    
    // Search occurrences in line
    function searchInLine(regex, line) {
        var match = regex.exec(line);
        return !match 
                ? null 
                : {
                        offset: line.indexOf(match[0]),
                        length: match[0].length,
                        line: line
                  };
    }
    
    // Returns current milestones, to speed up file random reading in future
    self.getMilestones = function() {
        return milestones;
    }
    
    // Reads optimal number of lines
    // callback: function(err, index, lines, eof)
    self.readSomeLines = function(index, callback) {
        var place = getPlaceToStart(index);

        //offset, length, buffer, callback
        readChunk(place.offset, chunkSize, function readChunkCallback(err, buffer, bytesRead) {
            if (err) return callback(err, index);

            var eof = bytesRead < chunkSize;
            var inChunk = examineChunk(buffer, place.offset, bytesRead, place.firstLine);

            // Wanted line in chunk
            if (inChunk.firstLine <= index && index <= inChunk.lastLine) {
                getLines(buffer, inChunk.length, function(lines) {
                    if (index != inChunk.firstLine)
                        lines = lines.splice(index - inChunk.firstLine);
                    callback(undefined, index, lines, eof);
                })
                // Wanted line not in this chunk             
            } else {
                if (eof) return callback('Line ' + index + ' is out of index, last available: ' + inChunk.lastLine, index);
                place = inChunk.place;
                readChunk(place.offset, chunkSize, readChunkCallback);
            }
        })
    };
    
    // Reads exact amount of lines
    // callback: function(err, index, lines, eof)
    self.readLines = function(index, count, callback) {
        var result = [];
        self.readSomeLines(index, function readLinesCallback(err, partIndex, lines, eof) {
            if (err) return callback(err, index);

            result = result.concat(lines);

            if (result.length >= count || eof)
                return callback(undefined, index, result.splice(0, count), eof);

            self.readSomeLines(partIndex + lines.length, readLinesCallback);
        });
    };


    self.find = function(regex, index, callback) {
        self.readSomeLines(index, function readSomeLinesHandler(err, firstLine, lines, eof) {
            if (err) return callback(err);

            for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                var match = searchInLine(regex, lines[i]);
                if (match) return callback(undefined, firstLine + i, match);
            }

            if (eof) return callback(undefined);

            self.readSomeLines(firstLine + lines.length + 1, readSomeLinesHandler);
        });
    };
    

    self.findAll = function(regex, index, limit, callback) {
        var results = [];

        self.readSomeLines(index, function readSomeLinesHandler(err, firstLine, lines, eof) {
            if (err) return callback(err, index);

            for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                var match = searchInLine(regex, lines[i]);
                if (match) {
                    match.index = firstLine + i;
                    results.push(match);
                    if (results.length >= limit)
                        return callback(undefined, index, true, results);
                }
            }
            if (eof)
                return callback(undefined, index, false, results);

            self.readSomeLines(firstLine + lines.length + 1, readSomeLinesHandler);
        });
    };
}

// LineNavigator wrapper to work specifically with HTML5 File object
function FileNavigator (file) {
    var self = this;
    var size = file.size;
    
    file.navigator = this; // reuse milestones later
    var lastPosition = 0;

    var getProgress = function() {
        if (!size || size == 0) return 0;

        var progress = parseInt(999 * (lastPosition / size));
        return progress > 999 ? 999 : progress;
    };

    // callback(err, buffer, bytesRead)
    var readChunk = function (offset, length, callback) {
        lastPosition = offset + length;
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function(progress) {
            var buffer;
            if (reader.result) {
                buffer = new Int8Array(reader.result, 0);
                buffer.slice = buffer.subarray;
            }
            callback(progress.err, buffer, progress.loaded);
        };

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file.slice(offset, offset + length));
    };

    // callback(str);
    var decode = function(buffer, callback) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(progress) {
            callback(progress.currentTarget.result);
        };

        reader.readAsText(new Blob([buffer]));       
    };

    var navigator = new LineNavigator(readChunk, decode, { chunkSize: 1024 * 1024 * 4 });
    
    // Returns current milestones, to speed up file random reading in future
    self.getMilestones = navigator.getMilestones;

    // Reads optimal number of lines
    // callback: function(err, index, lines, eof, progress)
    // where progress is 0-100 % of file 
    self.readSomeLines = function (index, callback) {
        navigator.readSomeLines(index, function (err, index, lines, eof) {
            callback(err, index, lines, eof, getProgress());
        });
    };

    self.readLines = function (index, count, callback) {
        navigator.readLines(index, count, function (err, index, lines, eof) {
            callback(err, index, lines, eof, getProgress());
        });
    };
    
    self.find = navigator.find;
    
    self.findAll = navigator.findAll;

    self.getSize = function(callback) {
        return callback(file ? file.size : 0);
    };
}

var started, finished;

function InitDemo(title) {
    $('#meta').html('');
    $('#output').html('');        
    
    if ( $('#file-select')[0].files.length == 0 || $('#file-select')[0].files[0] == null) {
        $('#meta').html('Please, choose file!');
        return null;
    }
    
    var file = $('#file-select')[0].files[0];
    
    $('#meta').append(title + '<br>');
    $('#meta').append('');
    
    started = new Date();
    finished = null;
    
    return file;
}

function DemoFinished(metaInfo, results) {    
    $('#meta').append('' + (metaInfo ? '<br>' + metaInfo : ''));
    $('#output').html(results ? results : ''); 
}

function Read() {
    var file = InitDemo('');
    if (!file) return;
    
    var navigator = new FileNavigator(file);
    
    var indexToStartWith = 0;
    
    var countLines = 0;
    
    navigator.readSomeLines(indexToStartWith, function linesReadHandler(err, index, lines, eof, progress) {
        if (err) { 
            finished = new Date();
            DemoFinished('Error: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        
        countLines += lines.length;
        
        if (eof)  {
            finished = new Date();
            DemoFinished('');
            return;
        }
        
        navigator.readSomeLines(index + lines.length, linesReadHandler);
    });
 
};

$('#read').click(Read);

var nextIndex = 0;

function FindNext() {    
    var pattern = $('#find-first-pattern').val();
    
    var file = InitDemo('Find of "' + pattern + '" pattern starting from ' + nextIndex);
    if (!file) return;

    var navigator = new FileNavigator(file);
    
    navigator.find(new RegExp(pattern), nextIndex, function (err, index, match) {
        finished = new Date();
        nextIndex = index + 1; // search next after this one
        
        if (err) { 
            DemoFinished('Error: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        if (!match) {            
            DemoFinished('No matching lines found');
            return;
        }
        
        var token = match.line.substr(match.offset, match.length);
        
        DemoFinished('Found matching token on ' + index + ' line', index + ': ' + match.line.replace(token, '<mark>' + token + '</mark>'));
    });
}
$('#search-beginning').click(function() {
    nextIndex = 0;
    FindNext();
});
$('#search-next').click(function() {
    FindNext();
});

function FindAll() {        
    var pattern = $('#find-all-pattern').val();
    
    var file = InitDemo('');
    if (!file) return;
    
    var navigator = new FileNavigator(file);
    
    var indexToStartWith = 0;
    var limitOfMatches = 999;
    
    navigator.findAll(new RegExp(pattern), indexToStartWith, limitOfMatches, function (err, index, limitHit, results) {
        finished = new Date();
        
        if (err) { 
            DemoFinished('Error: ' + err);
            return;
        }        
        if (results.length == 0) {            
            DemoFinished('No matching lines found');
            return;
        }    

        var resultsAsLine = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var token = results[i].line.substr(results[i].offset, results[i].length);
            resultsAsLine +=  results[i].line.replace(token, '' + token + '') + '';
        }

        DemoFinished((limitHit ? ' Limit of ' + limitOfMatches + ' is hit, so there can be more lines.' : ''), resultsAsLine);
  alert("Find All [Step 3] Called ");  
  
    });


  data=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($("#output").text()));   
 
  oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
  destroy: true,
  ajax: "data.json",
  data : data.aaData  
  }); 


alert("Alert  4");      
oTable.dataTable().fnClearTable();
alert("Alert  4 ClearTable"); 
oTable.dataTable().fnDestroy();
alert("Alert  4 DestroyTable"); 
//oTable.fnAddData(data);
oTable.fnDraw(); 
alert("Alert  5");


  
  function fnFormatDetails ( nTr ) {
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
    var sOut = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Rendering engine:</td><td>'+aData[2]+' '+aData[5]+'</td></tr>';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Link to source:</td><td>Could provide a link here</td></tr>';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Extra info:</td><td>And any further details here (images etc)</td></tr>';
    sOut += '</table>';
     
    return sOut;
}
  
  alert("Alert  5.1");
  setInterval( function () {
    oTable.api().ajax.reload();
}, 30000 );

  $('#example tbody td img').on( 'change', function () {
  var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
        if ( oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr) )
        {
   alert("Alert  5.2");
            /* This row is already open - close it */
            this.src = "../examples_support/details_open.png";
            //this.src = "http://l.yimg.com/rz/d/yahoo_news_en-US_s_f_p_168x21_news.png";
            oTable.fnClose( nTr );
        }
        else
        {
            /* Open this row */
   alert("Alert  5.3");
            this.src = "../examples_support/details_close.png";
   alert("5.3.1 this.src");
            oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(nTr), 'details' );
   alert("Alert  5.4");
        }

 alert("Base Function [Step 3] ");  
  
   });
  
alert("Base Function [Step 2] ");
 }

alert("('#searchAll').click(FindAll): Pre"); 
$('#searchAll').click(FindAll);
alert("('#searchAll').click(FindAll): Post"); 

//oTable.ajax.reload();

//$('#example').dataTable().ajax.reload();
});


alert("Step 1");
//data=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($("#data").text()));
function fnFormatDetails ( nTr ) {
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
    var sOut = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Rendering engine:</td><td>'+aData[2]+' '+aData[5]+'</td></tr>';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Link to source:</td><td>Could provide a link here</td></tr>';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Extra info:</td><td>And any further details here (images etc)</td></tr>';
    sOut += '</table>';
     
    return sOut;
}

//live is deprcated
$('#example tbody td img').on( 'click', function () {
        var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
        if ( oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr) )
        {
            /* This row is already open - close it */
            this.src = "../examples_support/details_open.png";
            //this.src = "http://l.yimg.com/rz/d/yahoo_news_en-US_s_f_p_168x21_news.png";
            oTable.fnClose( nTr );
        }
        else
        {
            /* Open this row */
            this.src = "../examples_support/details_close.png";
            oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(nTr), 'details' );
        }
    });  

//]]> 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've heard of some JSON parsers having trouble with tab characters. It looks like you have a tab in front of the `iTotalRecords` line.

Comment: I have removed Tabs and still does not work

Comment: I sorted out the soultuion. I cloned the Tag to Json Source declaration and reinitialized the table

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to Solve his mistry. Thank you Stackoverflow and Jsfiddle.net

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
 <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js'></script>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fiddle.jshell.net/css/normalize.css"> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fiddle.jshell.net/css/result-light.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.dataTables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
   <script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdn.dataTables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>  
  
</head>
<body> 
 <script id="data" type="application/json">
{ "sEcho": 1,"iTotalRecords": "11","iTotalDisplayRecords": "11","aaData": [  { "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>", "1": "Other browsers", "2": "All others",  "3": "-",  "4": "-",  "5": "U",  "extra": "hrmll"  },  {   "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",  "1": "Trident",  "2": "AOL browser (AOL desktop)",  "3": "Win XP",  "4": "6",  "5": "A",  "extra":"hrmll"   },  {  "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",  "1": "Gecko",  "2": "Camino 1.0",  "3": "OSX.2+",  "4": "1.8",  "5": "A",  "extra": "hrmll"  },  {  "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",  "1": "Gecko",  "2": "Camino 1.5",  "3": "OSX.3+",  "4": "1.8",  "5": "A",  "extra": "hrmll"  },  {  "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",  "1": "Misc",  "2": "Dillo 0.8",  "3": "Embedded devices",  "4": "-",  "5": "X",  "extra": "hrmll"  },  {  "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",  "1": "Gecko",  "2": "Epiphany 2.20",   "3": "Gnome",  "4": "1.8",  "5": "A",  "extra": "hrmll"  },  {  "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",  "1": "Gecko",  "2": "Firefox 1.0",  "3": "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",  "4": "1.7",  "5": "A",  "extra": "hrmll"  },  {  "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",  "1": "Gecko",  "2": "Firefox 1.5",  "3": "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",  "4": "1.8",  "5": "A",  "extra": "hrmll"  },  {  "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",  "1": "Gecko",  "2": "Firefox 2.0",  "3": "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",  "4": "1.8",  "5": "A",  "extra": "hrmll"  },  {  "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",  "1": "Gecko",  "2": "Firefox 3.0",  "3": "Win 2k+ / OSX.3+", "4": "1.9",   "5": "A",  "extra": "hrmll"  },  {  "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",  "1": "Misc",  "2": "IE Mobile",  "3": "Windows Mobile 6",  "4": "-",  "5": "C",  "extra": "hrmll"  } ] }
 </script> 

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th width="4%"></th>
   <th width="25%">Rendering engine</th>
   <th width="20%">Browser</th>
   <th width="25%">Platform(s)</th>
   <th width="16%">Engine version</th>
   <th width="10%">CSS grade</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="5" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tfoot>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th>Rendering engine</th>
   <th>Browser</th>
   <th>Platform(s)</th>
   <th>Engine version</th>
   <th>CSS grade</th>
  </tr>
 </tfoot>
</table>
 
<div id="meta"></div><br>


<input id="file-select" type="file" name="files[]" onchange="onFileSelected(event)" />
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[

var ajax="";
var fileselected="";
var olderfile="";
var data="";
var oTable="";
  var firstDivContent="";
  var secondDivContent="" ;
 
 
function onFileSelected(event) {
  var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  var result = document.getElementById("data");

  reader.onload = function(event) {
    result.innerHTML = event.target.result;
  };

reader.readAsText(selectedFile);
  reload();
  reload();
}
 
function reload(){ 
oTable.api().clear();
oTable.dataTable().fnClearTable(); 
oTable.dataTable().fnDestroy();
//alert("datatable cleared");
/*[{"0":"<img src='details_open.png'>","1":"Other browsers","2":"All others","3":"-","4":"-","5":"U","extra":"hrmll"},{"0":"<img src='details_open.png'>","1":"Trident","2":"AOL browser (AOL desktop)","3":"Win XP","4":"6","5":"A","extra":"hrmll"},{"0":"<img src='details_open.png'>","1":"Gecko","2":"Camino 1.0","3":"OSX.2+","4":"1.8","5":"A","extra":"hrmll"}]*/
 ///data=JSON.parse(updated);  

//Destroy the added Data
//oTable.dataTable().fnClearTable();
//alert("Cleared");
//oTable.dataTable().fnDestroy();
//alert("Destroyed");

 data=JSON.parse($("#data").text()); 

oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
 destroy:true,
 data : data.aaData
 }); 

oTable.api().clear();
oTable.dataTable().fnClearTable(); 
//oTable.dataTable().fnDestroy(); 

alert("Re-Initialized");
oTable.fnAddData(data.aaData);
oTable.fnDraw(); 
} 

$(window).load(function(){ 
//$(document).ready(function() {
 alert("ready");
 alert(data);
 data=JSON.parse($("#data").text());
 if(data!=""){
 alert('Inside OnReady');
 oTable = $('#example').dataTable({

 "processing": true,

 data : data.aaData
}); 
alert('Inside OnReady: Table Initialized ');
}
 alert("ready oTable Created");

 
function fnFormatDetails ( nTr ) {
  var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
  var sOut = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
  sOut += '<tr><td>Rendering engine:</td><td>'+aData[2]+' '+aData[5]+'</td></tr>';
  sOut += '<tr><td>Link to source:</td><td>Could provide a link here</td></tr>';
  sOut += '<tr><td>Extra info:</td><td>And any further details here (images etc)</td></tr>';
  sOut += '</table>';
 
  return sOut;
}

//live is deprcated
$('#example tbody').on( 'click',  'td',function (e) {
  var myImage = $(this).find("img");
  alert('myImage'+myImage);
  var nTr = this.closest('tr');
    alert('nTr='+nTr); //[object HTMLTableRowElement]
 
  if ( oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr) )
  {
  
  myImage.src = "../examples_support/details_open.png";
  //this.src = "http://l.yimg.com/rz/d/yahoo_news_en-US_s_f_p_168x21_news.png";
  oTable.fnClose( nTr );
  }
  else
  {
  
  myImage.src = "../examples_support/details_close.png";
  oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(nTr), 'details' );
  }

   alert("ready oTable refreshed");
  });
     
 alert("ready oTable Data added");
//This is not required as we are populating for the 1st time.
//oTable.fnAddData(data); 
//oTable.fnDraw();  

}); 

$(function() {
alert("('#searchAll').click(FindAll): Pre");
//document.getElementById("data").appendChild(oldFile);
//$('#searchAll').click(FindAll);
$('window').load(); 
alert("('#searchAll').click(FindAll): Post"); 
});

//]]> 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```